# Bash input redirection with newlines

Tags: java, bash, unit-testing, input, io-redirection

So for an assignment at school I am required to make a program in java that manages some students at a college, the user may invoke a number of function, but I started by testing 'add'.

My prof recommends that I use input redirection, because I can easily test the program over and over, without much typing.  Now here is the issue.

```
echo `< input.txt`
add Student Name 123 Street,City,Province,Postal Code q
#Input rediraction ate my newlines
cat input.txt
add
Student Name
Street,City,Province,Postal Code
q
#What I actually want to run
java -cp . TestCollege < input.txt #fail horribly
```

As you can see bash removes the newline characters I use to delimit my input, and thus my program crashes, because when you run it in interactive mode, Scanner.getLine() just blocks until input occurs.

Any idea how I can give my program the input with the newlines, it seems to work fine in windows "cmd" but not in "bash".

Comment: Do you want the input in (1) a single command line argument with newlines preserved, or (2) one command line argument per line of input, or (3) as standard input?  I assume not (3) and maybe you do want (2) — though that's trickiest to code.  (1) is handled by `"$(< input.txt)"` which adds double quotes around the 'back-quoted' command.  (3) is trivial, but you say it fails horribly.  Do you have a GUI or a simple I/O operations in the code?

Comment: The program does not take arguments, it reads from std in, I want to redirect a file to std_in w/ newlines preserved.

Comment: OK, that's my (3) and what you seem to use in the last line of your script.  The input will indeed have newlines preserved.  What does the code that is reading this information look like?  Time to explain what 'fail horribly' really means.  Does the scanner by any chance look for CRLF line endings instead of Unix-like NL (LF) line endings?

Comment: Is this real code? Backticks remove extra whitespace (including newlines), redirection does not. Your invocation of the real program uses no backticks so newlines should be preserved. Something is not right.

Comment: Scanner.nextLine(), looks for the line endings, based on the environment in which it is being executed.  As you can see by the above, bash is the problem, because input rediraction is consuming the newlines, wheras cat shows the file as is, and the last section is what I am trying to do.

Comment: What characters are in the file `input.txt`?  Do the lines in the file end Windows style with CRLF or Unix style with just NL (LF)?  Bash (probably) just hooks the file up to the input of the command; it has to decide whether that's a text mode or binary mode file, though.

Comment: Right now they are NL, I will try with windows line endings.

Comment: I expect that'll fix it.  `unix2dos` or `utod` are typical commands to fix this; you can also use `vim` and `: set filemode=dos` and then save the file to get CRLF line endings.

Comment: Input redirection doesn't do anything to newlines.  You could prove it by doing `cat <input.txt`.

Comment: Input redirection **does not** consume newlines. Backticks do. Try `cat < input.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try wrapping `BufferedInputStream` around `System.in`, because it can handle both cases:  `\r\n` and `\n`; and I think that's where your problem lies.

Or rather, call `useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"))` on `Scanner`.

Comment: Well, it reads all data from STD_IN, so I guess I could programatically open a file, and make that STD_IN.  Although that's not in the spec, so if anyone could figure out why bash removes the newlines, that would be prefered.

Comment: You should be able to read standard input in the ordinary way.  Are you running `bash` on Windows?  Could the trouble be that `bash` is only sending NL (newline) at the end of each line, but the reading code knows it is on Windows so it expects lines to end CRLF (carriage return, line feed — where LF = NL as a character code)?

Comment: Nope I'm on a macintosh, otherwise I would be using cmd, 'cause I know that works, I think if I toy with the terminal settings and the line endings, eventally I'll find a combo that works, though that is likely the problem.

Comment: @awiebe: Mac OS X is a regular Unix machine with NL as the expected line ending.  (Mac OS 9 or earlier used CR only as a line ending, to the confusion of all and sundry on different machines.)  So, to resolve this, you need to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct (Compiling) Example](http://sscce.org/) of your code.  It should be about a dozen lines or so of Java, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can see how bash does not eat the newlines running

```
$ wc -l < input.txt
```

Which I guess will give you the value you'd expect.

Comment: This is true, I guess echo eats the newlines

Comment: Ok, I'll just keep tinkering with it and post here when I resolve the issue thanks for the help guys.